# InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations

Tags: firebase

Once again, I'm trying to set up a database on firestore. It's a very simple one which would store emails list from my landing page. But I can't getting work.

The Javascript Console, throw this error:

```
InvalidStateError: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations."
```

This is my security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{databases}/documents {
     match /emailList/{list} {
       allow create: if true;
       allow update: if true;
       allow delete: if false;

     }
  }
}
```

It might be something easy, but this project already carried out with my patience

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your FireFox is setup correctly.

For IndexedDB to work you need history turned on.

Options > 'FireFox will Remember history'